# On the Transfer Homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, transfer-theory

I'm approaching the study of the transfer homomorphism between groups, and I found this exercise:

Given a finite group $G$ and a subgroup $H<G$, the set of left cosets of $H$ in $G$ is written $ \{x_iH \}_{i \in I}$ . Now I want to prove that, given $g \in G$ for all $i \in I$ there exists uniques $j\in I, h_i \in H$ such that $gx_i=x_jh_i$.

The fact that the indices of $x_i$ and of $h_i$ have to be equal for every $i \in I$ confuses me a little bit about the existence. In fact if I want to prove this for the first attempt I'm able to re-order the $h_i$ in order to make the equation hold (follows from the fact that cosets forms a partition of $G$), but once I've take this choice how can I show that I can find proper indices?

If I suppose the existence to be satisfied then the uniqueness is quite trivial because given $j,j' \in I$ then $gx_i=x_jh_i=x_{j'}h_i \implies x_j=x_{j'}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first think about what the question is really saying: if I take an element $g$ of my group $G$ and multiply it by a coset representative $x_i$,then it should land in another coset hence be written in the form $x_jh_i$ for some $h_i\in H$ and other coset representative $x_j$. (Since $G$ is fixed, $h_i$ only depends on $x_i$ hence the same indices, but a priori $x_j$ can be any representative hence the different index.) As you note, this follows from the fact that cosets partition $G$ (assuming you are allowed to use this fact for the exercise).

Comment: Thanks, ok so I think I understand the problem now. The fact is, tell me if I'm right, that once I've listed the cosets representatives $x_i$ then the choice of the $h$ to make equation holds, depends only on the coset representative and so we write that $h$ as $h_i$. 

I find this notation a little bit unclear or not intuitive.

Comment: Yep you are right (that there exists some $h$ making the equation hold follows from the partitioning, and then the $h$ is uniquely determined because it must be $x_j^{-1}gx_i$). The notation shouldn't be that unclear: we can't call just call it $h$ because that would seem to imply that the $gx_i=x_jh$ holds for EACH $i\in I$, so we distinguish the possibly different $h$'s by adding the index $i$ corresponding to the original closet representative. We could also think of it as a function from coset reps to $H$ and think $h_i=h(x_i)$ if you'd rather.